# Is there a most efficient way than random numbers to get a unique identifier on function call (jquery)?

Tags: jquery

I'm having this trouble: I created a plugin that generates and appends a `<div>` to my `<body>`, but this `<div>` has an id and if I call this functions multiple times my website crashes for obvious reasons, I can't use a class because I need unique attributes for my appended div, I solved this problem by creating a random number and adding it to my id, like this:

```
var unique_number = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000001);
var tempImg = '<img id="tempImg'+unique_number+'" src="' + path + ' "/>';
$('body').append(tempImg); 
//And I use it like
$('#tempImg'+unique_number).load(function(){ //blabla }
```

But I'm pretty convinced that this is not the best way of doing this, does anyone have another   better/most efficient solution? Thanks.

Comment: It appends a what to your what?! ;) Just kidding...but make sure you put HTML tags in code formatting or they won't show and your question becomes very confusing.

Comment: why not use the current timestamp as an id? something like: my_div_id_currenttimestamp ?

Comment: Just use a counter and increment it every time you create an element. Random numbers, being *random*, can't be relied on to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `length` property:

```
var count = $('img[id^="tempImg"]').length + 1;
var tempImg = '<img id="tempImg'+count+'" src="' + path + ' "/>';
```

Comment: I believe you would get repeated Ids with this approach since, for example, tempImg1 and tempImg2 have the same length.

Comment: @HyperD: The `length` of a jQuery object is the number of elements in it, not the length of its `id`.

Comment: @icktoofay: You are totally right. That's what happens for staying up late :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually use a counter if I really needed a unique (to that page) identifier, but you don't actually need an `id` here:

```
var img = $('<img src="' + path + ' "/>');
img.load(function() {
    // ...
});
img.appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Thank you, but this "non-id" solutions won't work out for me, I need the id because into the load function I got to use "$(this).width();",  what I'm actually doing is that: getting the url of a background-image propriety, creating an element with that, checking it's width and height and then destroying the element

Answer (score 1):

You can write this in one-string-function:

```
$("<div/>")
  .appendTo("body")
  .append($("<img>", { "src": path })
            .load(function () {
              // do smth
            })
  );
```

Comment: Why are you attaching the `load` event to the `div`?

Comment: Yep, you're right, i've noticed a few more mistakes. Fixed ;)

Comment: Thank you, but this "non-id" solutions won't work out for me, I need the id because into the load function I got to use "$(this).width();",  what I'm actually doing is that: getting the url of a background-image propriety, creating an element with that, checking it's width and height and then destroying the element

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define a counter, and increase it each time you create a new element.

```
var nextId = (function(){
    var prefix = 'some_really_uniq_string_';
    var id = 0;
    return function(){
        return prefix + (id++);
    };
})();
//each time you create a new element, call nextId()
```